# Split components into smaller components while keeping the `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` binding of the parent components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, split, components

I have a `main.component` that needs splitting into smaller components while keeping `ngModel` and `ngModelChange` of the parent component. How do I achieve such effect? I have tried [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html), but it doesn't seem to do anything to ngModelChange.

Example:

```js
//main.component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'main-component',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss'],
})
export class CardRendererComponent {
    private data;
    private method() {
        //...
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- main.component.html -->
<div class="componentA" [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="method()"></div>
<div class="componentB" [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="method()"></div>
```

What should I do to keep the `[(ngmodel)]` and `(ngModelChange)` property on that child component (`componentA.component.html` and `componentB.component.html`) so that I can achieve the following:

```html
<!-- main.component.html -->
<componentA [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="method()"></componentA>
<componentB [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="method()"></componentB>
```

Comment: Your smaller components would need to propagate the change events up the chain (@Output + EventEmitter).

Comment: @GunnarB.: I was trying to think of a cleaner way to do it. I have finally discovered the proper way to do it with ControlValueAccessor. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to do this properly without emitting and catching all the events between the components. I'll be using `ControlValueAccessor`. I'll leave the code here for those who need in the future:

```js
//componentA.component.ts - Child component
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'componentA',
    template: `<input
            [(ngModel)]="dataPassedByParent"
            (ngModelChange)="propagateChange(dataPassedByParent)"
        >`,
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => HeadingEditorComponent),
        multi: true 
    }],
})

export class ComponentAComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    dataPassedByParent;

    propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

    //Triggered when a value is written
    writeValue(data: any) {
        if (data) this.dataPassedByParent = data;
    }

    //Trigger on ngModelChange
    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    //Trigger on touched, required but not used
    registerOnTouched = () => {};

    constructor() {}
}
```

And in the parent component:

```js
//main.component.ts - Parentcomponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'componentA',
    template: `
        <componentA [(ngModel)]="data" (ngModelChange)="method()"></componentA>
`,
})

export class MainComponent {
    data;

    constructor() {}

    method() {
        //...
    }
}
```